# Can I ask about wp6.1 update error code?

Tags: discussion

I decided to try and update my old wp6.1 device but it gives me an error. I deleted all certificates using regedit analog, but I then got another error code and all internet messages say it's related to ActiveSync, but this isn't the case for me.

I suspect that this might not be an easily answerable question or that it might be out of scope of this site. Am I allowed to ask about this problem here and do you think there are users who may have an answer to it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately Windows Mobile is off-topic for this site.

Your would be best to post on another site such as http://forum.xda-developers.com/windows-mobile